# How to make an image in div tag responsive?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 but can't seem to get my image in a banner to be responsive when I narrow the browser.

I have a banner where I'm wanting to only show about 80% of an image. I was show how to do that with CSS yesterday, however, it's not responsive to a small browser. The image is 1400x350 and when I pull in the browser to mimic a tablet or mobile the image doesn't scale smaller based on the browser size.

Here is my code to use a div to display only a portion of the image.

```
.banner {
  background-image: url('../Images/banner.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  height: 155px;
}

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="banner"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I tried setting it up to use img-responsive but that didn't make a difference. It still won't scale.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <img src="~/Images/banner.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Based on my searching, using the img-responsive should have worked but it didn't. I will say that I think Bootstrap is working because I have a Grid under the banner. When I resize the browser the Grid will resize/stack like it should.

Comment: Currently you've got what you want. `.img-responsive` sets `width: 100%`and `height: auto`on your img. Since you're using a 12 column grid, your img gets big. Try using `col-md-1`instead, and you will see your image shrinking. In order to get it responsive the way you want, you may use custom css.

Comment: Your second solution works as [you can see here](https://jsfiddle.net/pcp01nbz/). The banner image is resizing.

Comment: I agree, based on what I've found the second version should work but it's not. There must be something else going on but I haven't been able to figure it out yet. This shouldn't be that hard and I'm not doing anything out of the ordinary.